# Missing $ inserted error when using \pi

Tags: pdftex, amsmath

I wanted to write down an equation however it seems that whenever I use `\pi` I keep on getting `Missing $ inserted` error
Here is my code:

```
$u_k = 2\cos(2^kr\pi)$
\subsection{Create an equation for $u\textsubscript{k+1}$  using $u_k$}
$u_k = 2 \times  \Re(e\textsuperscript{2ir$\pi$ })$ 
\\
$u\textsubscript{k+1}
=  2 \times \Re(e\textsuperscript{2\textsuperscript{k+1}ir\pi })
= 2 \times \Re(e\textsuperscript{2\superscript{k}ir\pi }\textsuperscript{2})
\Leftrightarrow
\\ 
2 \times( \cos^2(2^kr\pi ) - \sin^2(2^kr\pi ) )= 4\cos^2(2^kr\pi ) - 2$
```

Here of a few of my many errors:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.125 ...superscript{2\textsuperscript{k+1}ir\pi }
                                                  )
? 
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\mbox  #1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}
                                 
l.125 ...superscript{2\textsuperscript{k+1}ir\pi }
                                                  )
?
```

Just in case it matters I'm using the amsmath package.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. For superscripts in math mode there is `^`: `e^{2^{k+1}ir\pi}` is the correct code. Similarly `$u_{k+1}$` for subscripts.

Comment: Hmm, It doesn't seem to work. The errors are excactly the same.

Comment: Fix `\Re(e\textsuperscript{2ir$\pi$ })` into `\Re(e^{2ir\pi})`

Comment: Thanks it works now.

Comment: `\textsuperscript` is for when you're in text mode, and what's inside is also in text mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I supposed it is something like this you're trying to obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\begin{document}

$u_k = 2\cos(2^kr\pi)$
\subsection{Create an equation for \boldmath $u_{k+1}$ using $u_k$}
\begin{fleqn}
 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  u_k = {}& 2 \times \Re(e^{2ir\pi}) & & \\
u_{k+1}={} & 2 \times \Re(e^{2^{k+1}ir\pi }) = 2 \times \Re(e^{2^{k}ir\pi^{2}}) & & \\[-1ex]
\ArrowBetweenLines*[\Updownarrow]
 & 2 \times( \cos^2(2^kr\pi ) - \sin^2(2^kr\pi ) )= 4\cos^2(2^kr\pi ) - 2
\end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]